# How to test a method call in a constructor with rspec

Tags: ruby, constructor, mocking, rspec

i have a constructor like this:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(options)
    @options = options
    initialize_some_other_stuff
  end
end
```

and want to test the call to `initialize_some_other_stuff` if a instantiate a new Foo object.

I found this question [rspec: How to stub an instance method called by constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316294/rspec-how-to-stub-an-instance-method-called-by-constructor) but the suggested solution to call `Foo.any_instance(:initialize_some_other_stuff)` does not work in my rspec version (2.5.0).

Can anyone help me to test this constructor call?

Answer (score 0):

In you spec, you could have the following:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :initializer_called
  def initialize_some_other_stuff
    @initializer_called = true
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.initializer_called.should == true
```

If the constructor calls the `initiaize_some_other_stuff` method, `foo.initializer_called` should be true.

Comment: Hi gnab, thx for your answer. The problem is, that i do not want the method `initialize_some_other_stuff` to be called, i want to mock it.

Comment: I understand. The code I posted effectively replaces `initialize_some_other_stuff` with a dummy (mock), and adds a little functionality for being able to determine if it has been called, needed since we cannot apply any listeners for this as the call takes place in the constructor. Your original `initialize_some_other_stuff` is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

stub_model(Foo).should_receive(:some_method_call).with(optional_argument)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `initialize_some_other_stuff` method is private to the class, you should not care if it executes or not. That said, if that method performs some expensive operation that you don't want your test waiting for, then it is quite okay to mock that operation.

So, if Foo looked like this:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :options, :other_stuff

  def initialize(options)
    @options = options
    initialize_some_other_stuff
  end

  def initialize_some_other_stuff
    @other_stuff = Bar.new.long_running_operation
  end
end
```

Then you could mock out the call to `Bar#long_running_operation` like this:

```
describe Foo do
  subject(:foo) { described_class.new(options) }

  let(:options) { 'options' }
  let(:bar) { instance_double(Bar, long_running_operation: 42) }

  before do
    allow(Bar).to receive(:new).and_return(bar)

    foo
  end

  it 'initializes options' do
    expect(foo.options).to eq(options)
  end

  it 'initializes other stuff' do
    expect(foo.other_stuff).to eq(bar.long_running_operation)
  end
end
```

Now, you're testing the assignments. But, you're not waiting on the expensive operation to complete.