# How to check calls to a method called from constructor in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

If I have a class where the constructor calls another function, how do I check that it was called and the right number of times?

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(count)
    count.times{self.do_something}
  end

  def do_something
    # whatever
  end

end
```

I want to say something like

```
n = 4
MyClass.new(n).should_receive(:do_something).exactly(n).times
n = 2
MyClass.new(n).should_receive(:do_something).exactly(n).times
```

but that fails because the call to do_something happens before should_receive gets attached to it (at least I think that's why).

```
expected: 4 times with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Or is it just wrong to call stuff like this from the constructor and I should refactor?

Also, this question is very similar to this one:

[rspec: How to stub an instance method called by constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316294/rspec-how-to-stub-an-instance-method-called-by-constructor)

but I'm hoping in the last 5 years the answer has gotten better than setting up manual implementations of a stubbed `new` call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new syntax for doing this is as follows:

```
allow_any_instance_of(ExampleClass).to receive(:example_method).and_return("Example")
expect_any_instance_of(ExampleClass).to receive(:example_method).and_return("Example")
```

[See the docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance)

Answer (score 2):

Expectations are meant to be placed before the code that will be expected to meet them.

```
MyClass.any_instance.should_receive(:do_something).exactly(1).time
MyClass.new
```

That should work.

Comment: but I don't want it on ANY instance.  I want it on this specific instance.  I may not know how many instances I will have and each one should be able to get 1 call and some may get another amount (sorry, that's not in my example) - updated example.  I know it's contrived, but I'm trying not to post a ton of code.

Comment: Is your `do_something` method doing something complicated? It seems to me like you should be testing for the state of the object after initialization rather than the expectation that a method should be called when initialized.

Comment: yeah, that was the part of my question where I was asking if I should just refactor.  If I don't get an answer on how to do this easily, then that's what I'll have to do.  At this point, it's a matter of pride, regardless of what is "best" :)

Comment: Agreed, you've pretty much given me something to figure out as well. If I can come up with something I'll update the answer :)

Comment: I posted an answer for what I did that works well enough, but isn't as clean as I would care for.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer is to use rspec spies.  The issue here is that you have to create a mock for the methods you want to make requirements on after the fact.  Turns out it's not hard, but you still have to enumerate them.  The `and_call_original` is the magic that makes the implementation not change.

```
MyClass.any_instance.stub(:method_name).and_call_original
```

Then you can just say:

```
MyClass.new(4).should have_received(:method_name).exactly(4).times
```

I'd still love to find a way that doesn't require you to enumerate the methods, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I came up with, but I don't like it:

Create a new method in Class that runs a block on the allocated, but not yet initialize'd object.  I put this in the `before` block in my spec file, but there's probably a better place for it:

```
class Class
  def rspec_new(*params, &block)
    o = allocate
    yield(o) if block
    o.__send__(:initialize, *params)
    return o
  end
end
```

Then call it like this:

```
MyClass.rspec_new(n){|obj| obj.should_receive(:do_something).exactly(n).times}
```

it seems to work, but you can't pass a block to your constructor.  At least not the way you normally do.  That's why I didn't override the regular `new` method.